# Redirect to another jsp page after submitting a form

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 jsp pages "/page1.jsp","/page2.jsp" and "file.java", after submitting a form from "/page1" i want to go to action method take some records from the database and go to the "/page2" with the records i have and list it. All is done but for some reason i cannot go to the "/page2" page it takes me somewhere else(another .jsp page).

I am using liferay and extending MVCPortlet class

Thanks in advance!!!.

```
public void AddCustomer(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws                  IOException, PortletException {

    ...

    pCustomer.setCustomerId(customerId);

    // set UI fields
    pCustomer.setName(cusName);
    pCustomer.setAddress(address);
    pCustomer.setComments(comments);
    try {
        PCustomerLocalServiceUtil.addPCustomer(pCustomer);
    } catch (com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
}
```

addCustomer.jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="addCustomersAct" name="AddCustomer">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/allCustomers.jsp"/>
</portlet:actionURL>  
<form method="post" action="<%= addCustomersAct %>">
 ...
</form>
```

allCustomers.jsp

```
<%for (PCustomer allCustomer : customers) { %>
<tr>
 ...//List of all customers
</tr>
<% } %>
```

On top of the addCustomers.jsp i have some more portlet parameters because I have a sidemenu and i need them for the render requests.

Comment: Could you show some code?
Usually a form redirects to the page that is listed in the action-attribute inside the form tag.

Comment: Please provide more information like some sample code. We can't diagnose without seeing the patient.

Comment: Have you looked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562050/how-do-redirect-in-liferay-from-first-jsp-on-second-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **catch** block you can add following code statement.

```
actionResponse.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
```

Comment: i get an error message
09:35:58,451 ERROR [http-bio-8081-exec-32][render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: page2.jsp is not a valid redirect

Comment: i fixed it i had to paste whole url to the .sendRedirect() so it can work thanx a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your addCustomer.jsp create one renderURL and provide this as hidden parameter as redirect url

```
...
    <portlet:renderURL var="redirectURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/yourhtmlpath/confirm.jsp"/>
    </portlet:renderURL>
...
```

and

```
<form>
    ...
        <aui:input name="redirectURL" type="hidden" value="${redirectURL}"></aui:input>
    ...
</form>
```

In Your processAction method after doing your task:

```
...
    actionResponse.sendRedirect(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirectURL"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well would like to see more code snippet.Here it is to forward the request to another jsp

```
    String destination = "page2.jsp"; // using relative path here
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

make sure you are using right path for destination jsp

Comment: Unfortunately i am using portlet and i cannot use the .forward() method. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
 In place of mul change the object according to your requirement whatever value you want which is redirected to jsp
        actionRequest.setAttribute("mul",mul);
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/jsp/b.jsp");
In jsp:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<h6>Mul</h6>
<%= renderRequest.getAttribute("mul") %>
```